# Vue2: Memory Leaks

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have issues with components and watchers being generated, but not being destroyed properly when navigating to a new route via `vue-router`. Shouldn't this be handled automatically? Or, is there a way to reduce the number of watchers to make it more performant?

**Code Sample** *(Why the node and watcher counts get so high)*

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="record in data"
    @click.capture="rowClick(record)"
    @dblclick="rowDblClick(record)"
    :class="{ 'is-highlighted': isSelected(record) }">
    <td v-if="actionsVisible">
      <el-button-group>
        <el-button @click.stop="assign(record)" size="mini"><i class="fa fa-map-o"></i> </el-button>
        <el-button @click.stop="$emit('getActions', record)" size="mini" icon="more"></el-button>
      </el-button-group>
    </td>
    <td v-for="column in columns" :width="column.Width" :class="applyColors(record, column)">
      {{ formatData(record, column) }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Environment**

- `vue 2.3.0`
- `vue-router 2.1.1`
- `vuex 2.0.0`

Comment: It should be handled automatically AFAIK. I think this should get reported in the Github project where the maintainers can investigate it.

Comment: What does the rest of your code in this component look like?